# Android studio: Insert function in room isn't storing entity properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to store a entity with a foreign key into my room database. Let's say I have the field, which is the foreign keys value, set to 6. I followed it all the way until it's inserted and it stays 6, but for some reason it gets stored as 0. If I don't have an instance on the Parent Room Database of 6, it will crash as expected. But even when it does exist, it gets stored as 0. If it's an odd number, it get stored as a 1.

I can post some of the code, but I'd have to post a lot for everything to make that much sense and much would be redundant for the question. Anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Seems like an issue in your code. Room database does not exhibit this behavior.. Posting some code where you are inserting into the database and the entities declaration would be helpful to find the bugs.

Comment: Have you used @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) ?